# Magento custom "no results" search page

Tags: magento

Is there a way to define a custom template for the "no results" view of the Magento search?

The thing is that I want to use a 1 col layout if there's no result in a search, and 2 col if there is a match.

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i had the same issue: I hated that it was not easy to customise 'empty' pages i.e. empty search results, category pages and basket page.  So I made an extension a while back for this: https://github.com/drewhunter/EmptyHandles .  Essentially, it gives you 3 extra layout handles:

1. catalogsearch_result_index_empty
2. catalog_category_view_empty
3. checkout_cart_index_empty

So in your specific case, you would use the following xml to change the template on an empty search results page after installing the module:

```
   <catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
```

Comment: Mr. Hunter. If you were here right now I would have bought you a beer! Thank you very much, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Mr. Hunter, My Bad.. This didnt work for me.. I have placed all the files in their path, But no use?? Is there any other way?? Help me on this..

Comment: You have to activate the module in System / Configuration / General / Design / Empty Handles Module.
Thanks Drew!!

Comment: Cheers, Drew. This has been helpful!

Comment: Just one thing that had me stumped for about 10 minutes (it's late!).

You missed:

      <reference name="root">
      </reference>

Around the action there.

Answer (score 0):

If Drew Hunter's answer is not working for you:

1. Check that your permissions are correct.
2. Make sure you include the root reference in **emptyhandles.xml**

   ```
   <catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
       <reference name="root">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
           </action>
       </reference>
   </catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
   ```